# sum values in power pivot using criteria from different table

Tags: excel, dax, relationship, powerpivot, datamodel

I have been provided with two tables 1. sales table and 2.Items and it's characters. (The second table has two or more lines for one item if it has more than one characters)

[image]

I am trying to get the sum of sales value for the items based on its characters.

I have created a unique characters table and a unique material tables to link to other tables

In power pivot I am able to get the sum of sales by the material in U_Material, but if I include the Characters from U_Item and characters, then I am getting all the characters in the table and the sum, but actually it has only one characters (other characters are repeated with same value). what can i do to solve this.

if I don't include the materials or put them in filter then I get the overall sales value in the output but not as per the category.

[image]

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your model. Your Fact table "Sales" are filtered only by U_Item any of your other tables don't have an impact on it; You should change the model to star/snowflake. Put "Sales" in the center, rest of your tables (Dimension) connect by relationship one to many (many on Sales side);

Comment: Thank you @msta42a can you please let me know how to quickly convert the data I have  to star/snowflake model?

Comment: In sales you should have unique product id / item id; item table should have relation to additional characteristic

Comment: I was able to create a unique Product id based on the items table, but still it looks the same. there is relation ship between the U_Item, Sales (Material and ID), relationship between U_Item, U_Item and characters (material and ID). since the sales and the character tables have more than one line for a single material, i am unable to have a relationship between them.

Comment: try to create a unique id for your product table; For example if i have product id = 100 and company sell it i different colour, then I can create a id as product_id + UniqueColorNumber (the number should be of a fixed length); then from product i can make relationship to table where i have "color specification"; 

If you have problem with modeling then create a new thread where you show your current relationships + data example.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find solution by creating a measure.